# Manage.py migrate fails in this Heroku python "Get Started Guide" at Step 14 "Provision a Database"

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku

Here's the link to the guide:

[Getting Started on Heroku with Python](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#provision-a-database)

The guide says to run: `heroku run python manage.py migrate` which produces the following output:

... Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.   Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.

So then I run

`>heroku run python manage.py makemigrations` and get:

Running python manage.py makemigrations on ⬢ sleepy-reef-12488... up, run.5322 (Free)
Migrations for 'hello':
  hello/migrations/0002_auto_20200125_2146.py
    - Alter field when on greeting

Then re-running the first code: `heroku run python manage.py migrate` produces the same message as before.

The end result is this template error at: [my test app](https://sleepy-reef-12488.herokuapp.com/db/)

TemplateSyntaxError at /db/

'staticfiles' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
static
tz

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    https://sleepy-reef-12488.herokuapp.com/db/
Django Version:     3.0.2
Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:

'staticfiles' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
static
tz

Exception Location:     /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in find_library, line 1025
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version:     3.7.3
Python Path:

['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python37.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages']

Server time:    Sat, 25 Jan 2020 21:46:47 +0000

Comment: RESOLVED: I resolved my own problem from reading this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321684/staticfiles-is-not-a-valid-tag-library-template-library-staticfiles-not-found

replace load staticfiles with load static

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here:

['staticfiles' is not a valid tag library: Template library staticfiles not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321684/staticfiles-is-not-a-valid-tag-library-template-library-staticfiles-not-found)

I replaced

% load staticfiles %

with

% load static %

in a couple of files and now my app works. I can't tell you why this works. I wish I could. I'm new to Django.